# JSON DeserializeObject with Class RootObject

Tags: c#, json, class, deserialization, json-deserialization

Hey all I have the following json string:

```
{  
   "status":{  
      "msg":"Success",
      "code":0,
      "version":"1.0"
   },
   "metadata":{  
      "music":[  
         {  
            "external_ids":{  },
            "label":"Atlantic Records",
            "release_date":"2010-09-13",
            "album":{  
               "name":"Passion, Pain & Pleasure"
            },
            "title":"Bottoms Up",
            "duration_ms":"242013",
            "genres":[  
               {  
                  "name":"R&B\\Soul\\Funk"
               }
            ],
            "acrid":"63b14329c3beafe35cf08b144a2b4a31",
            "result_from":3,
            "artists":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Trey Songz"
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "timestamp_utc":"2016-08-18 13:56:40"
   },
   "result_type":3
}
```

That I am trying to get the following properties:

```
label
album > name
title
duration_ms
genres > name
artists > name
```

The C# code I have is:

```
dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<mReconize.musicJsonReturn.RootObject>(json);
Console.WriteLine(data["metadata"]["music"].label);
```

Naturally the **data["metadata"]["music"].label** is causing an error but i'm not sure as to why?

> Additional information: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'mR.musicJsonReturn.RootObject'

[image]

Comment: Try `data.metadata.music[0].label`

Comment: Care to share why down voted???

Comment: Wasn't me, but perhaps because it pretty obvious how you access the value from the screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Console.WriteLine(data.metadata.music[0].label);
```

You don't work with an array but an object.

And never ever use dynamic.

Comment: "never" use dynamic?! There's plenty of times when it's quite useful.

Comment: Exactly, so why did you say "never"?

Comment: And please learn how to format your posts. (i.e. code formatting, spelling and no smiley faces)